# Removing double values from a column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, count, unique, rows

[image]

I need to know how many different items are produced by each company (ID). 
The result should be this:

> - Company 1 = 4 (A,B,C,D)
> - Company 2 = 1 (B)
> - Company 3 = 2 (A,B)
> - Company 4 = 2 (A,B)

Which code should I use to get there? I guess it should be something that allows me to count the unique values for each ID.

Thanks

Comment: One way would be: `count(df, ID, Items)`.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `split()`+`unique()`+`nrow()` to make it, i.e.,

```
cnt <- sapply(split(u<-unique(df),u$ID),nrow)
```

or just

```
cnt <- table(unique(df)$ID) # from comments of @H1
```

such that

```
> cnt
1 2 3 4 
4 1 2 2
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4), 
    Items = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```